# Path to XML dataset in DBUnit

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, integration-testing, dbunit

I am using DBUnit for my integration tests and I was able to create a XML dataset. I added the dataset.xml file in the resources folder (standard Maven project). However when I try to just say `new File("dataset.xml");` it doesn't find the file and it prints that it tried to combine what I wrote with the path of my glassfish domain folder. I tried with an absoulute path and it works...but that can't be the right way of doing it?

```
FlatXmlDataSetBuilder builder = new FlatXmlDataSetBuilder();
IDataSet dataSet = builder.build(new File("/home/dude/Projects/Java/SecretProject/Code/Backend/SuperApp/src/test/resources/dataset.xml"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in my IntelliJ project...

I was using file import via annotation

```
@DatabaseSetup("UserServiceTest.xml")
```

and placing identical to java package tree in resources solved my problem i.e.:

```
src
  -main
    -test
      -java
        -com/site/service
          -userServiceTest
      -resources 
        -com/site/service
          -UserServiceTest.xml
```

Comment: Thanks, solved my issue too + note a leading "/" eg @DatabaseSetup("/UserServiceTest.xml") will pick up xml file from src/test/resources root directory rather than relative directory